# PHP mail out not working

Tags: php, html, css, email

doing some quick web dev work for a local body modification parlour just in my spare time; I'm trying to setup a Contact Us form, except when I hit submit, it just returns the die(); method. I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong, because i'm used to programming Java, and I'd just get the error method for that. Haha. My code is as below if anyone is able to help me, the problem area is within the "contact" case.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Darklite Tattoo & Piercing</title>
<link href="src/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /></link>
</head>
<body bgcolor="000048" />
<?php include("src/config.php"); ?>
  <div align="center" /><img src="src/img/darklite_banner.jpg" /><br />
    <div id="main" />
        <?php echo("<a href=\"index.php\" />Home</a> &middot; <a href=\"index.php?x=profiles\" />Profiles</a> &middot; <a href=\"index.php?x=services\" />Services</a> &middot; <a href=\"index.php?x=contact\" />Contact Us</a>"); ?>
            <hr>
            <?php
                $x = $_GET['x'];
                switch($x) {
                    case "profiles":
                        echo("Le profiles.");
                    break; case "services":
                        echo("Body piercings and tattoo's.");
                    break; case "contact":
                        if ($_POST["email"]<>'') { 
                            $ToEmail = 'ihatejava@hotmail.com'; 
                            $EmailSubject = 'Site contact form '; 
                            $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
                            $mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
                            $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
                            $MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."<br>"; 
                            $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."<br>"; 
                            $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["comment"])."<br>"; 
                            mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 
                        ?> 
                        Your message was sent
                        <?php 
                        } else { 
                        ?> 
                        <form action="index.php?x=contact" method="post">
                        <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                        <td width="29%" class="bodytext">Your name:</td>
                        <td width="71%"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="32"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td class="bodytext">Email address:</td>
                        <td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="32"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td class="bodytext">Comment:</td>
                        <td><textarea name="comment" cols="45" rows="6" id="comment" class="bodytext"></textarea></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td class="bodytext">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="left" valign="top"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send"></td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        </form> 
                        <?php 
                        }; 
                    break; default:
                        echo("Welcome to Darklite Tattoo & Piercing!");
                    break;
                }
            ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the error yor are getting ?

Comment: No error, it just goes straight to the die("Failure"); method.

Comment: Print the last error:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php

Comment: check your SMTP server is running

Comment: I added a "print(error_get_last());" to my code; no output.

Comment: I'm running this from my local apache server, if that makes any difference. I am also using Ubuntu.

Comment: Your system level mail call is being rejected... you need to find where sendmail puts its error messages.  Try /var/log/messages.  It won't be a PHP or Apache error, since mail() is operating normally, and it's probably not in /var/log/mail, since your mail isn't making it far enough to be processed by your MTA.

Comment: Okay I went to /var/log/, there's no messages folder, and the mail.err and mail.log files are both empty.

Comment: Try a date-ordered listing to see which log files have been modified recently. What is your MTA and how is it configured? Some MTAs put their logs in a subdirectory of `/var/log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a mail via `php` you need an smtp server. You can set it in your `php_ini` config file or by invoking `ini_set` beofre using `mail` function:

```
ini_set('sendmail_from', '$from');
ini_set('SMTP', '$smtp_server_address');
ini_set('smtp_port', $smtp_port);
mail(...);
```

Comment: I ended up just creating a free web hosting thing, and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

are you testing it on the localhost if yes then you have to setup a mail server in your localhost some of the mail servers are `sendmail`, `postfix` you have to configure one of them to your local system